# Listen to input value change on host of directive

Tags: angular, angular-directive

I am trying to implement a directive for input elements, which detects whenever the value of the input element changes. I am able to detect changes made by the user. However, my chnage detection does not work, when the host element is bound via `ngModel` and the model value changes.

```
modelChanged = new Subject<any>();

@HostListener("ngModelChange")
onModelChange() {  
  this.modelChanged.next();  
}

constructor(private host: ElementRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {

   var stateChange$ = merge(
      this.modelChanged,
      fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'input'),
      fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'change'),
      fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'cut'),
      fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'paste'),
      fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'drop'),
      fromEvent(this.host.nativeElement, 'keydown'));

   stateChange$.subscribe(d => { this.do() });
}
```

With this markup:

```
<textarea directiveSelector name="boundProp" [(ngModel)]="boundProp"></textarea>
```

When `boundProp` changes in the model without the user typing in the textarea, the action is not triggered. Why?

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can use a getter and setter for the model instead of host listner

```
 private _boundProp: type = null;

get boundProp(){
  return this._boundProp;
}

// trigger when model changes
set boundProp(val){
  this._boundProp = val; 
  this.modelChanged.next();  
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't really understand... The property is not defined on the directive but in the model of the component which uses the directive in its markup... Can you show where the code goes and how the markup looks?

Comment: mark up is pretty much the. code goes to you component which has the textarea